# VBA to fill an existing value down until last row

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a working macro that is transposing 5 rows into columns and append them after the last column.

The problem is that I need a long format so basically I want to automate the filling up, with the same data, until the end of data (basically the last row). I have 600 files and all these files have a different number of rows.

```vb
Sub LoopFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                'your code here
                Range("A2:B6").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Range("I10").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                    False, Transpose:=True
                Rows("1:8").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                With Sheets("Calculated Saccades")
                    .Range("I3").AutoFill .Range("I4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
                End With
                ActiveWorkbook.Save
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

The `With Sheets` is returning an error. Any ideas? Thank you so very much!

Comment: "An error" - please be more specific.

Comment: Just so you know if you write `Range("A2").Resize(10,1).Value = 1`  it will fill 10 cells under `A2` with the value 1.

Comment: Also a naked `Range()` call (for example `Range("A2:B6").Select`) acts on `ActiveSheet` which may or maynot be the sheet you want the range on. Always be specific on what worksheet you are reading values for. VBA is far too permissive with these things and it is dangerous when you don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting the point here. The sheet is declared :
With Sheets("Calculated Saccades")
                    .Range("I3").AutoFill .Range("I4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
                End With

Answer (score 1):

You're already inside a `With...End With` block (`With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)` - this loops through workbooks if you select more than one in the File Open dialog box); you can't nest these.

You can simply replace

```
    With Sheets("Calculated Saccades")
  .Range("I3").AutoFill .Range("I4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
```

with:

```
    Sheets("Calculated Saccades").Range("I3").AutoFill
    Sheets("Calculated Saccades").Range("I4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

You should also read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Thanks for the very swift response! You are absolutely correct about the With. 
Unfortunately, this line of code is returning an error: Runtime Error 438
Object doesn’t support this property or method

I have tried to run is separately, in a single sheet, just for test, and I get Compile error, invalid or unqualified reference and .Rows is highlighted in blue. 
Thank you again!

Comment: my bad...missed the second call to `.Range`.  Corrected again.

Comment: Also, I have tried a separate macro, that I can run on all files after the initial copy/paste/transpose, to avoid the loop Still no luck. It returns an error (Argument not optional for the Autofill. 

Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Calculated Saccades")

With ws
  Range("I3").AutoFill
  Range ("I4:I" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
'ws.Range("I3").AutoFill
'ws.Range ("I4:I" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub

Comment: `you can't nest these` - yes you can.

Comment: Thank you. Anyhow, is there a simple code line(s) that allow me to fill down automatically one column, with the value from a specific cell (I3 here), until the end of data (variable number of rows)?